# Socket.io recovery from disconnections

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have a chat with a server and a client in Socket.io. The client sends and receives messages to / from the server. In order to test a disconnection event, I pull out my Ethernet plug and reattach it after a few seconds.

After that sending messages from the client still works just fine and all previously sent messages during disconnection are resent successfully on both Chrome and Firefox.

For receiving however, it is OK for Chrome but not for Firefox which doesn't receive messages from the server anymore.

The question is what do I do to properly handle such network problems and make my chat robust?

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting. For example: `socket.on( 'disconnect', function () {
    console.log( 'disconnected from server' );
    window.setTimeout( 'app.connect()', 5000 );
  } );`

Comment: socket.IO supports ACKs (https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements) you can use that to detect if data was sent or not and react respectively. At least this is how I am handling such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root of the problem. Socket.io does reconnect out of the box just fine so you don't need to try to reconnect. However the socket does not seem to be rejoined to the same room after successful reconnection. I managed to solve the problem like this:

```
socket.on('reconnect', () => {
  socket.emit('onEnter', data);
});
```

Here `onEnter` event is used to make the server join me to the room.
However I do not understand why it couldn't retain the room as well.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the docs and like you said, the socket *should* be reconnecting itself normally. Since you can send messages, it seems you are halfway reconnected.

There is a couple events that would be worth for you to add in order to see if nothing is out of the ordinary: `reconnecting`, `reconnect_attempt`, `reconnect`, `reconnect_error` and `reconnect_failed`.

If nothing comes out of this, what I would advise you to do would be to check if you are getting a disconnect event in your client and recall your connect function, so you get a brand new socket after the network is reestablished:

```
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  // reconnect
})
```

From past experiences there was some dirty state stored in the socket object that could explain your issue, and it's worth it to start over with a clean one.

---

Note for people who do not need the socket-io client, there is also a little library that allows to do just that, reconnect gracefully in case your network drops and should work with a socket-io backend too, [reconnecting-websocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket).

Comment: I catch the following events in this order in both browsers: `disconnect`, `reconnect_attempt`, `reconnecting`, `reconnect_error`, `reconnect_attempt`, `reconnecting`, `reconnect`. Seems fine. How do I implement this `// reconnect`? Without this the answer is not complete.

Comment: And which reconnect is it, from server or client?

Comment: At least the advice to listen to these events did help me better understand what is happening